# Express Multer does not work when using node version 14.15.1

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have the following snippet of code:

```
var fileUpload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
    }
 })
});

router.post("/addFile", fileUpload.single('newFile'), function (req, res) {
  let _id = req.body.someId;
  console.log("Adding File with id: " + _id);
  // some database inserts and response
  ...
```

This code works 100% fine in node v12. I can upload files of any size, however once I change to node v14.15.1 the upload behaves odd for anything larger than about 60KB. Looking at the file system I can see the upload worked however nothing inside the route was executed. So I can see the file on the filesystem but that `console.log` and any database commands won't execute.

Looking at the request I never appear to get back a response header for files larger than 60KB on node 14. I assume not getting a response header to my request is why the upload is failing.

The following is the javascript that performs the file upload.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('newFile', $("#newFile")[0].files[0]);
formData.append('someId', $('#someId').val());

$.ajax({
   url: './addFile',
   data: formData,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function (data) {
     console.log('success upload')
});
```

---

I found the cause of the problem but don't know of a fix. The if I set `res.local` the upload fails. If I comment it out the upload will work. Does anyone know of a fix/workaround for this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.connection = mysqlConnection;
  res.locals = {
    version: '1'
  };
  next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `req.connection` to `req.dbconn` this seemed to have fixed the issue.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   req.dbconn = mysqlConnection
   res.locals = {
      version: 'version'
   };
   next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two lines of code:

```
  req.connection = mysqlConnection;
  res.locals = {
    version: '1'
  };
```

should be avoided because both req.connection and [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) are sort of reserved objects in express, the first contains connection data, like IP and other headers, while the second should be used for variables scoped to the current request. Depending on what else you are doing in the code, you are overwriting these two, and most likely breaking something that in this case shows as a bug in multer. You have fixed the `req.connection` problem, but still you may break other middleware/functions that use `res.locals`, so instead of reinitializing it like you do, you can just add your own property like:

```
res.locals.version = '1'
```

Comment: You're 100% correct. My issue boiled down to the `req.connection`  it would be great if the [express api docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) mentioned that.  Thanks for pointing out the potential issue I have with reinitializing `res.locals` I'll change that code right away.

Comment: looks like [node.js http api doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_connection) makes mention of the request.connection (deprecated) Anyway even though I already answered this question myself I'll give you the +50 since you pointed out other issues with my code.

Comment: Yes, you solved the actual problem since also you had more context to the code, but this was more to shed some light on why it was breaking the way you had it. Still though I feel puzzled as to why the Node version affects this, but I assume since `req.connection` is deprecated in Node 13, most likely Node 14 is breaking the library code that uses it, so the library must be updated to support Node 14.